# How to setup Openwisp-radius with Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, openwisp

I am trying to get started with openwisp-radius with django project. after setting up my django project with openwisp radius when i run
`py manage.py migrate`

i run into this error

> Applying openwisp_radius.0013_remove_null_uuid_field...Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1280, "Incorrect index name 'nas_uuid_694a814a_uniq'")

Answer (score 1):

Try again with the latest version of OpenWISP RADIUS:

```
pip install -U openwisp-radius
```